# I do not have the option to trade an artifact with Vulgrim

Tags: darksiders

How do I trade artifacts with Vulgrim? It doesn't seem to give you that option when you go up to him and have what you can purchase open. Do I have to get them all first?

Comment: This definitely isn't about Terraria. Are you asking for Darksiders 1 or 2?

Comment: My guess is it's Darksiders 1.In 2nd part you have Relics instead of Artefacts and they work a bit differently.

Answer (score 3):

No,**you don't have to collect all of them** to be able to sell them.You can sell them one by one as you collect.

Here is how it should look,if you have artefact in your inventory and are talking to Vulgrim you should see in the **bottom** part of the screen the **quantity** of artefacts you have for sale and a **button** with which to sell them.

It could be that you collected **something else**(one of many different shards) instead of [artefact](http://darksiders.wikia.com/wiki/Artifact),**already sold** it by mistake or loaded a different game(**save/load issue**)

You can open up your inventory and see how many artefacts you collected so far.